# Difference in output when writing on console and writing to file in C

Tags: c, file-io, output, printf

I have the following code, in which I'm creating some processes and then printing something on the console and also writing something to the file. The problem is that I get the print once on the console but I get multiple file writes when I run the code. I'm unable to figure out what is causing this and how to make it work as I intend it to.  I want the line to be written just once to the file as well.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include "server.h"

#define QUELEN 256

main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  struct sockaddr_in manager, client;
  struct hostent *cp;
  int sockdescriptor, td;
  int len;
  int j;  
  pid_t pid;
  int dummy;
  char str1[32], str2[32];

  FILE* fp;
  FILE *output_fp;

  if ((output_fp = fopen("dummy.out", "w")) != NULL){
  }
  else{
    printf("output file not created\n");
  }

/* THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM IS */
   printf("just print this once on console\n");
  fprintf(output_fp, "just write this once to the file...\n");

/****************************** Forking Client Subprocesses ***********************************/
/*                                                                                            */    
/*                                                                                            */

   for(j = 0; j < 4 ; j++){
    if((pid = fork()) == 0){    // child process
//      dosomething();
        exit(0);        // terminate child process
    }
   }                    // end of the forking for loop

/*                                                                                            */    
/*                                                                                            */
/**********************************************************************************************/      
    listen(sockdescriptor, QUELEN);             // listening for incoming connections here   

  while(1) {
    len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    td = accept(sockdescriptor, (struct sockaddr *) &client, &len);

    if((pid = fork()) == 0){            // child process        

        close(sockdescriptor);          //closing listening socket    
        cp = gethostbyaddr((char *) &client.sin_addr, sizeof(struct in_addr), AF_INET);    
        close(td);      // client req. processed, close this socket
        close(sockdescriptor);
        exit(0);
    }               // end of ((pid = fork()) == 0)

    close(td);    
 }                  // end of while loop   

}                   // end of main
```

Output in the file:

```
just write this once to the file...
just write this once to the file...
just write this once to the file...
just write this once to the file...
```

Output on the command prompt:

```
just print this once on console
```

Comment: Yeah just did this and its working fine now. Someone had put this solution down, but seems like they deleted it before I could respond. Anyways I got this working with their suggestion
`sprintf(str1, "just print this once in file\n");
    fprintf(output_fp, str1);
    
    setvbuf(output_fp, str1, _IOLBF, 1024);`

Comment: So why not add an answer youself?

Comment: @ZahaibAkhtar, add an answer youself. You have to ;)

Comment: Alright, I just put my answer down, couldn't do so earlier because of the 8 hour restriction before you can answer you own question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference in the output is seen because the way the console and file writing is buffered. The console or the output uses line buffering whereas file writing is fully buffered. If I just change the file write to also be "Line Buffered" then I will get the same output in the file as that on the console. This can be done via `setvbuf()`

```
sprintf(str1, "just print this once in file\n");
fprintf(output_fp, str1);

setvbuf(output_fp, str1, _IOLBF, 1024);
```

Answer (score 1):

The author answered this himself...so, closing this to prevent this coming up in Uanswered set.

> > > > author's answer...not mine <<<<
> > > >         Yeah just did this and its working fine now. Someone had put this solution down, but seems like they deleted it before I could respond. Anyways I got this working with their suggestion sprintf(str1, "just print this once in file\n"); fprintf(output_fp, str1); setvbuf(output_fp, str1, _IOLBF, 1024); – Zahaib Akhtar 8 hours ago